# Understanding the Lambda function in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to understand the code my professor gave me using the Lambda function below. I'm essentially struggling to understand how `l.TestSample(1, "GOOG")` results in an output given that `multiplier` in the lambda function is not defined (as far as I can see) and hence an Error should result.

```
#define a class
class LambdaSample(object):


#just a simple method that returns prices
def GetPrices(self):
    return {"GOOG":1080, "MSFT":30}


#executing
def TestSample(self, fxrate, ticker):
    #using 
    self.GetBasePrice = lambda multiplier, ticker: self.GetPrices()[ticker] * multiplier
    print(self.GetBasePrice(fxrate, "GOOG"))
    #continue doing more processing below
    #.....



l = LambdaSample()
l.TestSample(1, "GOOG")

print l.GetBasePrice(1, "GOOG")
```

Thank You

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Your code doesn't make sense as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code contains a lambda function: `lambda multiplier, ticker: self.GetPrices()[ticker] * multiplier`. So `multiplier` is an argument swallowed by this function.

For your purposes, the expression is actually a short form of the following:

```
def anonymous_function(self,multiplier,ticker):
    return self.GetPrices()[ticker] * multiplier
```

Comment: My struggle is why `multiplier` gets the value of `fxrate`. Does this imply that if a lambda function is within another function then they must have the same number of arguments as the arguments of the enclosing function are mapped to those of the lambda function? Thanks

Comment: `self.GetBasePrice(fxrate, "GOOG")` is a function invocation. In my example, it is like calling `self.anonymous_function(fxrate,'GOOG')`. It executes the function and passes those values.

Answer (score 1):

*multiplier* is the first argument of the lambda function that you assign to attribute *GetBasePrice*
When you call this function within *TestSample* method, it is assigned the value of *fxrate* argument.

Still, strange example....

**EDIT:**

There is no binding connection between the lambda function and the enclosing function in this example (a bad one, I must say).
The better example of lambda function usage is as a key, e.g.

```
In [13]: target = tuple((x, -x) for x in range(10))

In [14]: max(target, key=lambda x: x[0])
Out[14]: (9, -9)

In [15]: max(target, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[15]: (0, 0)
```

as you may see, I use lambda function to set criteria for maximum value search.
In the first case, the criteria is by the first element of the inner tuple, in the second - by the last.

Comment: Thanks. I'm essentially confused as to why `multiplier` takes on the value of `fxrate`. As I've mentioned above, does this imply that if a lambda function is within another function then they must have the same number of arguments as the arguments of the enclosing function are mapped to those of the lambda function? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused as to what the `key` is actually doing here (i.e. What search criteria the `lambda` is defining in the two case)

Answer (score 0):

A lamba function in Python takes the following form:

```
lambda x: something(x)
```

which is equivalent to

```
def lambda_fn(x):
    return something(x)
```

so, in your case, multiplier and ticker are not variables, but rather the parameters of your lambda function. Similar to how you can do

```
def test(ahdlkashdanlifblwaef):
```

without any problem, you can also do

```
lambda ahdlkashdanlifblwaef: <something here>
```

too without having to worry what `ahdlkashdanlifblwaef` is. It's just a name.

In your prof's example, the line `self.GetBasePrice = lambda multiplier, ticker: self.GetPrices()[ticker] * multiplier` is equivalent to:

```
def GetBasePrice(self, multiplier, ticker):
    return self.GetPrices()[ticker * multiplier
```

This is actually a fairly obtuse way of using lambda, as lambda functions are supposed to be anonymous, one-off/disposable functions; NOT instance methods. A better example of lambda would be:

```
str_list.sort(key=lambda text: len(text))
```

here you use lambda to quickly define a function that transform the string `text` to its length, and use that lambda function as the key to sort the list `str_list`.